# Unit testing with a "real" database using efcore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I've got a fairly complex application to test that uses EFCore, including things like NetTopologySuite. It runs on MS SQL Server locally and Azure SQL in the cloud and has to be tested against these, so in memory databases and SQLite are not enough. Is anybody aware of some helper framework to automate the creation/wiping of test databases? I've found EfCore.TestSupport, but it doesn't seem to support NetTopologySuite, which is a must have for us.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a unit test cannot use a real database, as you're then no longer testing a single unit of functionality. Using a real database makes your test a *systems test*, which is a much higher-level test, which should *not* be part of your build/CI pipeline. This is because the real database could fail, which would then fail your unit test, even if there's nothing wrong with your code (i.e. false negatives).

Additionally, you're "testing the framework" here. If you're going to use a library like NetTopologySuite, you should always ensure that it is itself well-tested, but you should not test it yourself. That is not *your* code. Likewise with EF Core. EF Core has an extensive test suite already, you do not need to, nor should you, test it yourself. Your responsibility is to test code you write, code that is unique to your application. Mocks and fakes should be used abstract third-party libraries like this. In other words, you'd simply use a fake/mocked data result that you'd get from NetTopologySuite and run that through your code, rather than *actually* using that library directly.